# PopUpWindow Back Key event

Tags: android

I saw many posts on this subject but couldnt find the right answer for me.

I have an activity that dims when i pop the popup window.
the back button working but only the second time i press it, the first press dismiss the popup but its not un-dim the activity because i cant catch the event from the popupwindows, the second press is catched by the activity and only then i can un-dim it.

here are my tries to accomplish this:

```
    m_PopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    m_PopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);


    View popUpWindowLaout = m_PopupWindow.getContentView();
    popUpWindowLaout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);


//first press doesnt get caught here
    popUpWindowLaout.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                m_ActionBar.show();
                unShadeTheActivity();
                m_PopupWindow.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

//this func will catch the second press and will work, but i want the first press will do it.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (m_PopupWindow != null)
    {
        m_ActionBar.show();
        unShadeTheActivity();
        m_PopupWindow.dismiss();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: remove your `else { super.onBackPressed(); }`, it ALWAYS should call `super.onBackPressed();` to un-dim the screen i guess. Hope this helps.

Comment: Call `super.onBackPressed` in all cases...or you can set a dismiss listener on popupWindow, in that you can call `finish();`

Answer (score 2):

change

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (m_PopupWindow != null)
    {
        m_ActionBar.show();
        unShadeTheActivity();
        m_PopupWindow.dismiss();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

to

```
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
    if (m_PopupWindow != null)
    {
        m_ActionBar.show();
        unShadeTheActivity();
        m_PopupWindow.dismiss();
    }
else
{
// rest of the code
// you can use finish,dismiss or call startActivity
// finish();

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
popupWindow.setOnShowListener(HandlePopupShowLister);
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(HandlePopUpDismissListerner);

public static OnDismissListener HandlePopUpDismissListerner = new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("HandlePopUpDismissListerner", "HandlePopUpDismissListerner");
        CommonVariable.IsPopupOpen = false;
    }
};
public static OnShowListener HandlePopupShowLister = new OnShowListener() {
 // onShowListener interface.
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.i("HandlePopupShowLister", "HandlePopupShowLister");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CommonVariable.IsPopupOpen = true;

    }
};
```